# Can you sync different AD domains under one Azure AD domain?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

My problem is that we have 2 On-Premises Active Directory domains:

- mycompany.com
- mycompany-dev.com

Some people are present in both of these AD-s. I want to sync them with Azure Active Directory so that they are all represented once, and all have the @mycompany.com suffix (instead of @mycompany.onmicrosoft.com). I also don't want some users to have @mycompany-dev.com in their azure AD account login name, so I want to do some sort of mapping I guess.

Is this possible with Azure AD Connect, or do I have to implement a synchronization method manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can sync multiple on-premises domain to Azure AD. Kindly check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-topologies) and you will get a detailed information about different topologies supported

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_bmu9fN4ISYg74JT&Q_CHL=gl
>